# ImportError: No module named 'selenium' in Sublime text plugin

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to create a sublime text plugin for running selenium python commands. Here is my code...

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

try:
    import unittest2 as unittest
except ImportError:
    import unittest

from selenium import webdriver

def run_tests(view):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.quit()

class RunSeleniumCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        run_tests(self.view)
```

This gives me an error as soon as I save the plugin script.

```
reloading plugin RunSelenium.runselenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 72, in reload_plugin
    m = imp.reload(m)
  File "./imp.py", line 276, in reload
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/RunSelenium/runselenium.py", line 9, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Normal selenium (written in python) scripts run fine.
What am I missing here?

Comment: what is the output of which selenium?

Comment: Sorry for asking a question in response but what do you mean by "which selenium"?

Comment: if you are on linux, open a terminal and type "which selenium". It will tell path of the executable if the selenium is installed on your system.

Comment: It gives nothing. No output.

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html follow this.

Comment: I have installed selenium using pip already (I don't need selenium server so haven't installed that). selenium is installed at `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76598/discussion-between-kishor-pawar-and-vikkun).

Answer (score 3):

Okay I checked if the installed location of selenium was there in `sys.path` variable. I added it and that solves the problem.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import sys

try:
    import unittest2 as unittest
except ImportError:
    import unittest

sys.path.append("/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages")
from selenium import webdriver

def run_tests(view):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.quit()

class RunSeleniumCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        run_tests(self.view)
```